# React Native with Redux-Persist , PersistGate inifinite loading

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, native, persist

I'm working on an app in react native and must work with Redux-Persist. I have the store configuration set up, no errors occur but the rehydration never happens and the persistentGate is infinitely in the loading state.

Here is my store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import  entriesReducer from './reducers/entries';

import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    entries : entriesReducer
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 // see "Merge Process" section for details.
   };

   const pr = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    const persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { persistor, store };
  };

  export default configureStore;
```

And my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';

const store = configureStore();

const RNRedux = () => (
    <Provider store={store.store}>

    <PersistGate loading={<App />} persistor={store.persistor}>

        <App/>

    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('PTM', () => RNRedux);
```

Any help will be very much appreciated, I've been trying to set this up for days now with no success. Previously I would have to deal with errors but now I don't see any and it still refuses to work, I simply don't know where to look for the fault.

Edit: 
App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; 
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import NavBar from './src/components/NavBar/NavBar';
import DayPicker from './src/components/DayPicker/DayPicker';
import TotalTime from './src/components/TotalTime/TotalTime';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen';
import EntriesList from './src/components/EntriesList/EntriesList';


var x = null;

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

And my HomeScreen is using this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        data : state.entries.data,
        entriesPerDay : state.entries.entriesPerDay, 
        pickedDate : state.entries.pickedDate,
        total: state.entries.total
      };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
          onPickDate: (day) => dispatch(pickDay(day)),
          onDataSet: (data) => dispatch(setData(data))
      };
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Comment: Could you show us App.js file? Because both loading component and main content are also <App />.
If you still couldn't figure out, are you running on silmulator? Maybe it's related AsyncStorage issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14101.

Comment: @HieuTran, I'm running on a simulator, 
The <App/> is there from experiments, switching to loadingscreen or anything else does nothing, the persist gate is constantly loading and the store never gets rehydrated. 
I'm not using AsyncStorage